# Which is the variance of a variable which is the linear sum of normally distributed random variables?

Tags: expected-value, variance, confidence-interval

I have a random variable $x$ which is normally distributed with expceted value $\bar{x}$ and variance $\sigma$:

$$x\sim N(\bar{x},\sigma)$$

As you know, i can consider $\bar{x}$ a random variable that, being the sum of multiple normally distribuited variables, is normally distributed. Now, in many sources on the internet people start explaining confidence intervals saying that the variance of this new random variable is $\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$, where $N$ is the sample size of the initial dataset. Can you derive the math to conclude that the variance of the expected value is equal to the original variance divided by the square root of the sample size?

Comment: The title can be misleading but  was not able to upload the question with the original title that i had in mind.

Comment: The normal distribution specification doesn't make sense.  The mean of a random variable is a constant, not another (non-constant) random variable.  If your question is computing the variance of the sample average in an iid sample, see [here](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat414/lesson/24/24.4).